# how to get bytea images from postgresql database and display them in django?

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

This is how I created a table:

```
sql_create_table = ''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images (
                                        image_id text PRIMARY KEY,
                                        image bytea,
                                        name text
                                        )'''
```

I have images and text data store in excel. I used openpyxl python library to read the excel data and insert them in the Postgres database.

I looked at the database table and saw the image store as binary data. Now, How should I get bytea data and display them using HTML.

**Store.html**

```
<div class="w3-container w3-center">
        {% load static %}
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <label>Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" value="{{image.0}}" class="file-upload">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="{{image_id.1}}"><br>
            <label>url:</label>
            <input type="text" name="url" value="{{name.2}}"><br>

            <button type="submit" value="update" name="update" class="file-upload-btn">Upload</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Python libraries I used:

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import psycopg2
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader
import PIL.Image as Image
import base64
```

I connect to Postgres and get the table data from python. Look at my code, I convert binary to base64 since HTML doesn't support binary data.

**views.py**

```
def images_display(request):
connection = connect_to_db()
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = 'SELECT * FROM images;'
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()

one_row = []
data = []

for value in results:
    for i in value:
        if isinstance(i, (bytes, bytearray)):
            one_row.append(base64.b64encode(i).decode("utf-8"))
        else:
            one_row.append(i)
    data.append(tuple(one_row))
    one_row = []

results_dict = {
    'images': tuple(data)
}

cursor.close()
connection.close()
return render(request, 'images.html', results_dict)
```

This is a display image HTML page

**images.html**

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto; margin-top: 10px;">
        {% for image in movies %}

            <li>{{image.2}} <img src='data:;base64,{{image.1}}' alt="no image display" style="width:500px;height:600px;" > </li>                     
        {% endfor %} 
    </div>
```

The images didn't display so, I inspect the page and it was showing

```
<li> name <img src='data:;base64,<memory at 0x0000020C9AB70580>' alt="no image display" style="width:500px;height:600px;" > </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 'movies' to 'images' in the template. It should work.

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto; margin-top: 10px;">
    {% for image in images %}
        <li>{{image.2}} <img src='data:;base64,{{image.1}}' alt="no image display" style="width:500px;height:600px;" > </li>                     
    {% endfor %} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem the solution is envelop the variable in a bytes function:

```
bytes(data_in_bytea)
```

In your case it is:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto; margin-top: 10px;">
    {% for image in movies %}

        <li>{{image.2}} <img src='data:;base64,{{bytes(image.1)}}' alt="no image display" style="width:500px;height:600px;" > </li>                     
    {% endfor %} 
</div>
```